# Вывод постов определенной категории

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте! Хочу сделать на сайте вывод постов только определенной категорий(с помощью id категории). Есть такой код:

```
$args = array(
 'numberposts' => '100000',
 'category' => 35,
 'post_type' => 'ad_listing',
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

но почему-то массив `$posts` пуст. Если убрать `'category' => 35` то выводит все посты нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что параметр категории называется cat, а не category.

И не надо писать 100000, для указания вывода всех постов, поставьте -1.

Comment: Все равно пустой массив(

Comment: Сделал с помощью `taxonomy`. Вроде все работает, спасибо!

Comment: А, ну конечно. Я не обратил внимания, что у вас кастомный тип записей.